# Google Docs API Adding a ressource to a collection (Zend/gdata)

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to do this following the API documentation there:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#adding_a_resource_to_a_collection

With the Zend PHP gdata Framework my code is :

```
$docs->insertDocument($entryFile,  'https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder%3A0B--Zn-zouTFrOXdrV3lRelhuNHM/contents');
```

[Documentation on this method](http://www.zendframeworkdocumentation.com/classZend__Gdata__Docs.html#aac7859c97301161c3698e2e0ef2a077c)

I don't know how to find the correct URI then...

The entryFile parameter is the right type, it's the url that cause the problem the error

Response from the server :

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date:
>   Wed, 25 Apr 2012 17:10:51 GMT Expires: Wed, 25 Apr 2012 17:10:51 GMT
>   Cache-control: private, max-age=0 X-content-type-options: nosniff
>   X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block Server:
>   GSE Connection: close Invalid request URI

The exception :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with
>   message 'Expected response code 200, got 400 Invalid request URI' in
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.6.1\www\workspace\library\Zend\Gdata\App.php:709
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.6.1\www\workspace\library\Zend\Gdata.php(219):
>   Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('POST', 'https://docs.go...',
>   Array, 'performHttpRequest('POST', 'https://docs.go...', Array,
>   'post(Object(Zend_Gdata_Docs_DocumentListEntry),
>   'https://docs.go...', NULL, NULL, Array) #3 C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.6.1\www\workspace\library\Zend\Gdata\Docs.php(300):
>   Zend_Gdata_App->insertEntry(Object(Zend_Gdata_Docs_DocumentListEntry),
>   'https://docs.go...', 'Zend_Gdata_Docs.. in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.6.1\www\workspace\library\Zend\Gdata\App.php on line
>   709

(If you need any info please let me know, i'm really stuck on this and i'm willing to give as much details as possible if needed)

Comment: Is there any way to have the complete URI logged? I suspect that the URI is being encoded twice, i.e. it should contain a : character, not a %3A encoded character.

Comment: Thanks for the hint I will give a look at the framework to see that ;)

Comment: Not it's not that i try to replace it with the ":" but it's not working when i do an echo in the method performHttpRequest() the url doesn't seems to be encoded because it's still look like this URL:https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder:0B--Zn-zouTFrOXdrV3lRelhuNHM/contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the Php Client Library for the Google Drive SDK

Answer (score 0):

Could you please log the exact HTTP request that is performed by Zend and compare it ti the one listed in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#adding_a_resource_to_a_collection

I'm sure the differences will show you what is done wrong.

Comment: Nivco thanks for your answer, i posted this like last month and i was really stuck on it, the gData framework from Zend really... suck. Because you don't have all the functionalities needed (for Google Docs) and it's way outdated. I'll get back on it in the next few months but with the Google Drive API this time probably ;)

Comment: Good idea :) The Drive API is way better documented for PHP :)